# I am little confused with the following codes in php

Tags: php

The code is as follow-

```
<?php
$i = 5;
while (--$i > 0 || ++$i)
{   
    print $i;
}
?>
```

The correct answer is `4321111.......`. But how could it start from 4, it should just strat from 5. In my opinion, the answer should be `55555555......`.

Comment: what output do you want to get?

Comment: `--$i` is pre-decrement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it starts with 4 because this statement is evaluated first `(--$i > 0 )`

which is `pre decrement`, that means it decrements first then evaluates the while loop

so here it is `checking whether i is greater than 0 or else increment i by 1`

so it `prints 4321`, when i reaches 0 the `--$i > 0` statement is not evaluated as i becomes 0 so the or part is evaluated which is +1

so the result becomes 4321111111.................

Comment: see the answer you will understand, || are known as or, so when one of the statements are true it will be evaluated, that means if --$i >0 gets false the ++$i will be executed

Answer (score 1):

If u give pre-decrement operator as condition in the loop statement it will start with one less than the value assigned initially . That is the reason why it starts from 4 instead of 5 .